# what am I doing wrong at the moment to validate my lesson class?

Tags: python, django

I want to validate if my lesson material belongs to a xyz user with pro right it will show the correct conent, but if not it will display become a member , but however I am getting if I change id membership to pro or vice versa it always `true` the statement

```
def get(self, request):
    template = loader.get_template(self.template_name)
    template_member = loader.get_template(self.template_payment)
    #rendering the template in HttpResponse
    lesson = Lesson.objects.first()
    user_membership = UserMembership.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).first()
    user_membership_type = user_membership.membership.membership_type
    lesson_allowed_mem_types = lesson.allowed_memberships.all()
    if lesson_allowed_mem_types.filter(membership_type=user_membership_type).exists():
        return HttpResponse(template.render())
    else:
        return HttpResponse(template_member.render())
```

models

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
  allowed_memberships = models.ManyToManyField(Membership)

class Membership(models.Model):
    membership_type = models.CharField(
        choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES,
        default='Free',
        max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.membership_type

class UserMembership(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  membership = models.ForeignKey(Membership, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.user.email
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you just trying to see if the user has a Membership?

```
if UserMembership.objects.filter(
        user=request.user,
        membership__membership_type="PAID MEMBER",
    ).exists():
    # user is member
    return HttpResponse(template.render())
else:
    # user is not a member
    return HttpResponse(template_member.render())
```